# How to do a For Each Item in an array in LESS css

Tags: css, less

I having trouble writing a for each item in LESS css

I am new to using less, if someone could show me an example I would appreciate it

I am using the following:

```
    "less": "^3.11.3",
    "node-less-chokidar": "^0.4.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
```

```
@values: 23, 14, 45;

    .as-test(@i: length(@a)) when (@i > 0) {
        @value: extract(@a, @i);

        .h-@{value}px {
         height: ~"@value"px;
        }        

        .as-test-(@i - 1);
    }

    .as-test(@values);
```

desired output:

```
.h-23px {
  height: 23px !important;
}
.h-14px {
  height: 14px !important;
}
.h-45px {
  height: 45px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this

```
@values: 23, 14, 45;

.loop(@list,@i:1) when (@i <= length(@list)) {
  @current: extract(@list,@i)+0px;
  .h-@{current} {
    height: @current !important;
  }
  .loop(@list,@i+1);
}

.loop(@values);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Abhishek Kumar Tiwari's (valid and working) answer:

```
@values: 23, 14, 45;

each(@values, {
  .h-@{value}px {
    height: unit(@value, px) !important;
  }
});
```

Read more: [each](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) (Less)